# Why do rendered images using a GPU have vertical lines in versions after 2.81?

Tags: gpu, opengl

While using GPU rendering I get vertical lines over the rendered object.

Until version 2.81 I don't get this anomaly, I thought it would be some bug in version 2.83, but in version 2.90 presents this same problem. Video card used is AMD RX 570 8Gb.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for this site, could you please translate your questions. If you are not comfortable writing it you can just use any online translation tool

Comment: This looks like a problem with either an unsupported graphics card, or out-of-date graphics drivers.

Comment: Installing the latest version (09/09/2020) of the video card software solved the problem.
Christopher Bennett, thank you!